# Refresh KML file stored on Google Docs

Tags: xml, google-maps, kml

I am experimenting with the network link to network link method of refreshing a static kml file.  I am currently pulling a KML, which gives all buoy locations, straight from NOAA via https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/kml/marineobs_by_owner.kml

However, I know that this file is static even though the KML itself has a 30 min refresh interval in it.

I have written an XML file, based on information obtained on this forum, to use network links to try and refresh the kml but could use a little assistance.  I first wrote a KML file and named it updating.kml using the http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0 namespace with a link to the KML file provided by NOAA.

Updating.kml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
     <Document>
     <NetworkLink>
     <Link> <href>https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/kml/marineobs_by_owner.kml</href>
      <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
      <refreshInterval>1800</refreshInterval>
     </Link>
     <name>SaltWx</name>
      <open>1</open>
    <visibility>1</visibility>
    </NetworkLink>
   </Document>
</kml>
```

I then uploaded the file to google docs which gave me a URL of 
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1YkJAGSHCQdxbLn-JyI7Jgz5ZV-0sFqIM     I inserted this URL into the second network link XML named networklink.kml using the same Google namespace.

networklink.kml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
  <Document>
  <NetworkLink>
    <Link>
    <href>https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1YkJAGSHCQdxbLn-JyI7Jgz5ZV-0sFqIM</href>
    <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
     <refreshInterval>1800</refreshInterval>
    </Link>
    <name>SaltWx</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <visibility>1</visibility>
  </NetworkLink>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Next, I uploaded the networklink.kml file to google docs and referenced its link in the HTML

HTML

```
<script>

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeId: 'satellite',
      center: {lat: 40.248, lng: -73.580},
      disableDefaultUI: true
    });

   var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1a7J3iBBBKzHE0oEG7-EsWaDy-Mxde9dz&amp;export=kml',
      preserveViewport:true,
      map: map
    });

  }
</script>
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work as the layer didn't appear so I am hopeful those more skilled than me can offer some suggestions.  Perhaps it is the namespace but I don't know.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? As you pointed out, the first KML file you referenced (marineobs_by_owner.kml) is already an auto-updating NetworkLink. Loading that on your map, it should re-fetch the data kml every 30min.  Looks like you added 2 layers of nearly identical networklinks on top of that, each updating every 30min, rendering the ones below them redundant. Do you mean something specific with "the network link to network link method"? Also, hosting KMLs on Google Drive can be tricky, since Share links don't directly download the file, but you seem to have made it work.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, @Christiaan. I really appreciate it.  So, the KML file retrieved from NOAA is set to update every 30 minutes but when I pull it to my site as a KML layer on GoogleMaps, it seems to refresh 2 hours behind the true data from NOAA.  My guess is that it is being cached by GoogleMaps.  I am trying to get the file to refresh every 30 minutes as intended by NOAA.  I had read on another Stackoverflow thread that one may be able to get around the cache by using a network link to a network link.

Comment: Ok, not sure why you would be seeing the delay. Caching is a possibility, but would need a test site and a bunch of work to confirm.  If you can link to the thread about using multiple networklinks, I would be curious to see it, and maybe provide feedback.